# i used a tp command on a clock and am trapped

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a disable all command setting or command or any suggestions on how to move, I am 1600 blocks away from the command but I know the coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the exact coordinates of the command block then I strongly suggest using `/setblock <x> <y> <z> air 1 replace`

If you don't know the coords, or they were the wrong ones, then go to your server destination folder and look for `server.properties` and edit it with notepad and look for a line called something like `enable-command-blocks=true` write false instead of true, save it, restart the server, go to the clock, and it, and then you can turn on command blocks on by writing true instead of false.